# php buscar conteudo de <p>

Tags: php, funções, preg-match

Como posso pegar o 'VALOOR'

```
<p id="sinopse2" style="display:block !important;">VALOOR</p>
```

Tentei esse código:

```
preg_match_all("#<p id=\"sinopse2\">(.*?)<\/p>#s", $string, $encontrou);
```

Mas não obtive sucesso ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o seguinte código:

```
preg_match_all("/<p[^>]*id=\"sinopse2\"[^>*]*>(.*)<\/p>/", $html, $output);
var_dump($output);
```

**Explicação do Regex:**

```
<p.+id=\"sinopse2\"[^>*]*>(.*)<\/p>
│  │       │            │     │   │
│  │       │            │     │   └────── Informa o limite da seleção
│  │       │            │     └────────── Captura o grupo que está entre `<p>`
│  │       │            └──────────────── Seleciona todos os caracteres até `>`
│  │       └───────────────────────────── Informa o ID do elemento
│  └───────────────────────────────────── Selecione tudo até o ID
└──────────────────────────────────────── Informa a tag
```

<sup>[**Demonstração**](https://regex101.com/r/gzqY4R/1)</sup>

Comment: sim, o código trabalhou muito bem agora !

Answer (score 0):

```
$qtd = '<p id="sinopse2" style="display:block !important;">VALOOR</p>';

$out = trim(strip_tags($qtd));

echo $out; //VALOOR
```

> **strip_tags** — Retira as tags HTML e PHP de uma string

[**Exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/B9VqH4)

Outro exemplo:

```
$qtd = '<p id="sinopse2" style="display:block !important;">Aqui temos o conteudo da tag p que não é necessariamente VALOOR</p>';

$out = trim(strip_tags($qtd));

echo $out; //Aqui temos o conteudo da tag p que não é necessariamente VALOOR
```

[**rodando - ideone**](https://ideone.com/Tue4zg)

Comment: desse jeito só funcionaria se o conteudo da linha sempre fosse "VALOOR" rs, acho que passei a minha idéia um pouco confusa, pois usei como exemplo 'VALOR' para nao ficar vazio a tag,o conteúdo pode ser vários, mais obrigado a intenção

Comment: @PauloPreviatto, não entendi seu comentário `conteudo da linha sempre fosse "VALOOR"` Você viu rodando no ideone?

Comment: assim agora entendi o código, ele retira tudo  em volta de "VALOOR" e deixa somente o conteudo, é isso ??

Comment: @PauloPreviatto, ele retira as tags e retorna o conteúdo (texto)

Comment: agora ficou claro para min, muito obrigado tambem por mostrar mais um meio de obter  um valor de <p>

Comment: @PauloPreviatto, não é só de `<p>` poderia ser de qualquer tag html